# Error while trying to run Windows application in Xubuntu Linux

Tags: xubuntu, windows, wine

While trying to install and run an application called Zone Builder (a mod-maker for SRB2) through Wine on Xubuntu Linux 22.04, I get the following errors:

```
env WINEPREFIX="/home/cran/.wine" wine-stable C:\\windows\\command\\start.exe /Unix /home/cran/.wine/dosdevices/c:/users/Public/Desktop/Zone\ Builder.lnk
0048:err:module:import_dll Library mscoree.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework64\\v2.0.50727\\mscorsvw.exe") not found
0048:err:module:LdrInitializeThunk Importing dlls for L"C:\\windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework64\\v2.0.50727\\mscorsvw.exe" failed, status c0000135
003c:err:service:process_send_command service protocol error - failed to write pipe!
00d8:err:module:import_dll Library mscoree.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v2.0.50727\\mscorsvw.exe") not found
00d8:err:module:LdrInitializeThunk Importing dlls for L"C:\\windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v2.0.50727\\mscorsvw.exe" failed, status c0000135
003c:err:service:process_send_command service protocol error - failed to write pipe!
cran@cran-MacBookPro:~/Desktop$ 010c:err:module:fixup_imports_ilonly mscoree.dll not found, IL-only binary L"Builder.exe" cannot be loaded
010c:err:module:LdrInitializeThunk Importing dlls for L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Zone Builder\\Builder.exe" failed, status c0000135
```

Is there anyway for me to get this Windows application running? Is there something else I need to install? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Zone Builder is not listed at winehq, so I don't think you can get much help here.

Comment: Check with `https://www.winehq.org`. Not all Windows programs are available through `wine`. This is not a Ubuntu problem, this is a `wine` problem.

Comment: You can run a Windows virtual machine (in principle you can use Windows 7 trial version without connecting it to the internet, and assign 1 GB RAM to the virtual machine. If you have a powerful computer, you can also use Windows 10), and run this program there.

Comment: Okay, in that case I'll just make a separate partition in my SSD or make a VM for Win7. I'm trying to also do some YouTube editing with Vegas so VM might be my best option.

Comment: Try: `apt-cache search SRB2` to see if there's a Ubuntu package for you.